# How to fetch the Line before Runtime Error

Tags: java, string

I am logging my error in the logging file. The content of the file is in following format.

```
INFO: Trying to find a cam application file.    
Jul 14, 2014 3:14:33 PM com.tgcs.scrt.ui.components.cam.CamProcessor start
INFO: Processing cam file at c:/scrt/cam/index.cam
Jul 14, 2014 3:14:33 PM com.tgcs.scrt.ui.components.cam.CamProcessor start
WARNING: Error parsing composite application markup (CAM) file: c:/scrt/cam/index.cam . Falling back to log viewer. 
Throwable occurred: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The end-tag for element type "page" must end with a '>' delimiter.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)    
    at com.tgcs.scrt.ui.components.cam.CamProcessor.build(CamProcessor.java:425)
    at com.tgcs.scrt.ui.components.cam.CamProcessor.start(CamProcessor.java:557)
    at com.tgcs.scrt.client.application.MainPart.createComposite(MainPart.java:93)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:877)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:333)
```

I just wants to capture following line from the file

```
WARNING: Error parsing composite application markup (CAM) file: c:/scrt/cam/index.cam . Falling back to log viewer.
Throwable occurred: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The end-tag for element type "page" must end with a '>' delimiter.
```

Currently I am using following implementation

```
    private String createErrorMessage( String logContent ) {
    String[] messages = logContent.split( "\n" );
    StringBuffer message= new StringBuffer();
    for(int i=0;i<messages.length;i++) {
        String tempMessage = messages[i];
        if(tempMessage.indexOf( "Throwable occurred" ) >=0) {
            message = message.append( "\n" ).append( messages[i-1]).append( "\n" ).append( messages[i]);
        }
    }
    return message.toString();
}
```

but I am sure a better version would exists. I just do not wants to create temporary array by splitting the content.

Comment: Why not use exception.getMessage()?

Comment: I can not access the exception class over there. it is a RCP plugin and I am bound to read the log messages from the log file.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to split the string and make a temporary array, you can use a regular expression instead, like so :

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("WARNING.*\\nThrowable.*\\n");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(error);
    if(matcher.find())
        return matcher.group();
```